# Select 50 previous rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm fairly new to using MSSQL and have run into a weird problem. Given the first record id from the last query, I need to find the 50 rows before that that meet the same criteria as the first query and return them in descending order. This is for an ASP.NET site, and I'm pretty sure the ASP side is correct but it gives the wrong results when I try to run the SQL query

This is the SQL I've been trying

```
 WITH PreviousPosts AS 
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
    WHERE (A_1STNAME LIKE '(variable)%')
    AND A_RECID < '(lastPost)'
 )
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM PreviousPosts
ORDER BY A_RECID ASC
```

where "(variable)" and "(lastPost)" are actually filled in with the correct parameters with my C#

I'm no longer receiving errors  but now I'm getting the same results no matter what is provided as the lastPost.

Update: The results are the first 50 in the table that have firstnames like (in my test case) "James"

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think that after you fix that first problem you'll still have another unless you change `LIKE (variable)%)` to `LIKE '(variable)%')`. Unless it only looks like that because of how you modified it when putting it into your question.

Comment: Yeah, that and the missing table name were both just me failing at writing my sql for the question, sorry everyone!

Comment: @JavaJosh94 Can you please edit your question with the property SQL so we can help you out?

Comment: Edited it to match what I'm currently at with my SQL. I'm not receiving errors anymore, but I'm getting weird results. It's not giving the previous results instead it's giving results that come about 100 after the lastPost

Comment: Also I just noticed no matter what is provided as the lastPost, it's giving the same results.

Comment: @JavaJosh94 Just a FYI, your question and SQL don't match still. You say you're not receiving errors anymore with the SQL that is currently in the question, but the question text is all about it throwing errors due to syntax.

Comment: @JavaJosh94 Is A_RECID an identity column?

Comment: @JeremyPridemore to be honest I'm not completely sure, if I made the database I would've gone with something simpler rather than what this person did. The database is converted from Visual Fox Pro, and the A_RECID field is in the form yyyymmddssuuu y = year m = month d = day s = seconds u = user

Comment: @JavaJosh94 Oh wow... well, I had an example query, but I doubt the `A_RECID < '(lastPost)'` check is going to work for you because it's going to be doing string comparisons, not true time comparisons or identity comparisons like you want. Hmm...I think that could still be done. I have a hard time seeing why they would store year, month, day and second with no hours or minutes. o.O Usually people stop precision at some point, not skip parts of precision. Is there any other date or time column on the table?

Comment: @JeremyPridemore that's what it said in the documentation he gave me, but he's like 68 and wrote this in his 20's so I could see him being a little off on that. Either way, the only other date or time column is one he made to store the persons birthday, but he never checked to make sure users filled it out so in most of the entries it's empty

Comment: @JeremyPridemore my plan was to make the CTE contain the posts in descending order, then take the top 50 from that and return them into assending order for output. But then I was told you can't use ORDER BY in a CTE.  I have no problem getting the next 50, using "WHERE A_RECID > (lastPost)" but I'm having problems getting the previous ones :(

Comment: @JavaJosh94 I tried giving you an answer. Even if it is wrong, you might be able to use the ROW_NUMBER() technique in the CTE and then filter on that. Also, I tried pulling the date out of the A_RECID because you gave me the format which has a date in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt, with what I know of your schema now. I still had to make more assumptions than I'm comfortable with, so this might not be right as is:

```
;WITH RankedRecords AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A_RECID DESC) Row
        , A_RECID
    FROM [database]..[table]
    WHERE A_1STNAME LIKE '(variable)%')
        AND CAST(LEFT(A_RECID, 8) AS DATE) < CAST(LEFT('(lastPost)', 8) AS DATE)
)
SELECT TOP 50
    T.*
FROM[database]..[table] T
INNER JOIN RankedRecords
    ON RankedRecords.A_RECID = T.A_RECID
    AND RankedRecords BETWEEN (@LastPost - 51) AND (@LastPost - 1)
ORDER BY RankedRecords.Row
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I never would've figured that out!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the table name in your CTE.  See `**[TABLENAME]**`

```
 WITH PreviousPosts AS 
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM [database].[dbo].**[TABLENAME]**
    WHERE (A_1STNAME LIKE (variable)%)
    AND A_RECID < (lastPost)
    ORDER BY A_RECID DESC
 )
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM PreviousPosts
ORDER BY A_RECID ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated earlier, you're missing the table name in your CTE.  You are also missing which columns you would like to take from the CTE.

You should change:

```
SELECT TOP 50 FROM PreviousPosts ORDER BY A_RECID ASC
```

to:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM PreviousPosts ORDER BY A_RECID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the list, you can't have an order-by inside a CTE. In order to get what you want, ditch the CTE altogether:

```
SELECT top 50 * 
FROM [database].[dbo].**[TABLENAME]** 
WHERE (A_1STNAME LIKE (variable)%) 
AND A_RECID < (lastPost) 
ORDER BY A_RECID DESC
```